# In Windows 8 Pro vsersion, do we have .NET framework (4.5) or we need to download it from Web?

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework

I am using Windows 8 Pro, but when I am trying to install any game or software, I get an pop up error message, that you dont have .NET framework. So I am just little worried, please help me

Comment: **.NET Framework 4.4 does not exist**. .NET Framework 4.5 is installed by default on Win 8.0 and .Net Framework 4.5.1 is installed on Win 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound, Ohh sorry, it was about 4.5 only. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the software you are trying to install requires an older version of .NET Framework and doesn't have the installer bundled with it. Try the solution suggested [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/net-framework-windows-8).